# Browser Shortcut link getting modified with some URLs

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

I have a problem with my browser links in desktop(firefox and chrome), it's getting modified with http://yeabd66.cc/ link with the shortcut and whenever I open the browser it directs to that link. How can I get rid of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

Run Malware-bytes on your computer then delete the shortcuts from your desktop and make new ones with out the bogus url in it. also make sure you homepage isn't set to go there